# How to compare string differences between two separate column of sheets in Excel-VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuTkA.jpg) [Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTgN3.jpg)

Above i have two images link that i have captured from my excel document (Sheet1, Sheet 2)

Here's a brief description basically, I just want my macros to compare Part Number (column C) from both sheets and find out the differences. And when a string differences is detected between both sheets it will highlight the row on both sheet of BOM-list to indicate to the user the differences in the Part-number(column C). But that is a problem too as seen in the images there is some rows with "space" which the loop have to take care of to prevent comparing an empty string thus giving wrong result.

Sorry for my poor command of English and explanation if its not clear to you. Can someone guide me on this i'm rather aimless on where or how to start and i have to complete this within a week without prior knowledge on excel-VBA programming understanding.

**Updated:**

I have updated my post can someone take a look and give me your opinion on how i can change the code to highlight the whole row of column A to P instead of column C Range value differences only?

```
Sub differences() 

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet 
    Dim lastRow1 As Integer, lastrow2 As Integer 
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, temp As Range, found As Range 

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") 

    lastRow1 = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
    lastrow2 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 

    Set rng1 = ws1.Range("C21:C" & lastRow1) 
    Set rng2 = ws2.Range("C21:C" & lastrow2) 

    For Each temp In rng1 
        Set found = Find_Range(temp.Value, rng2, , xlWhole) 
        If found Is Nothing Then 
            temp.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 
        End If 
    Next temp 

    For Each temp In rng2 
        Set found = Find_Range(temp.Value, rng1, , xlWhole) 
        If found Is Nothing Then 
            temp.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 
        End If 
    Next temp 


End Sub 

Function Find_Range(Find_Item As Variant, Search_Range As Range, Optional LookIn As Variant, Optional LookAt As Variant, Optional MatchCase As Boolean) As Range 

    Dim c As Range 
    Dim firstAddress As String 

    If IsMissing(LookIn) Then LookIn = xlValues 'xlFormulas
    If IsMissing(LookAt) Then LookAt = xlPart 'xlWhole
    If IsMissing(MatchCase) Then MatchCase = False 

    With Search_Range 
        Set c = .Find(What:=Find_Item, LookIn:=LookIn, LookAt:=LookAt, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=MatchCase, SearchFormat:=False) 
        If Not c Is Nothing Then 
            Set Find_Range = c 
            firstAddress = c.Address 
            Do 
                Set Find_Range = Union(Find_Range, c) 
                Set c = .FindNext(c) 
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress 
        End If 
    End With 
End Function
```

Comment: Besides, images (at least for me) are unreachable without register...

Comment: @Tiago Cardoso Could you try again see does it work?

Comment: @Vivian I just tried, still need to register

Comment: @Vivian it is likely that people will not want to register on a site, just to help you. Maybe you could do screen captures to partially represent your sheets instead.

Comment: @Nathan Fisher can you take a look above i have made some changes? How do i highlight the row instead of just differences in column c?

Comment: @datatoo i have updated my post above can you take a look and give me your opinion on how i can change the code to highlight the whole row of column A to P instead of column C Range value differences only?

Comment: @Vivian, now we're able to see them. Will have a look once possible.

Comment: @Vivian, some further questions... please clarify in your post: 
1) is there any reason that prevents you to sort the data in column C in both sheets? 
2) Your idea is to verify what are the Part numbers that exists in one sheet and doesn't in another, compare them based on the row index or use the Part Number as a pivot and compare other values for the same row? Could you please give us examples of rows that should be highlighted?
3) The other columns' data matter at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I cant see the the images, I will make the assumption that what you are trying to do is check if a part number exists in the other list and if not then highlight it.

Off the top of my head this is what you will basically need to do.

```
Public Sub Test()
    CompareRange Sheet1.Range("A2", "A8"), Sheet2.Range("A2", "A8")
End Sub


Public Sub CompareRange(range1 As Range, range2 As Range)
    Dim CompareCell As Range
    Dim CheckCell As Range
    Dim CellFound As Boolean
    For Each CompareCell In range1.Cells
        CellFound = False
        For Each CheckCell In range2.Cells

            If CheckCell.Text = CompareCell.Text Then
                CellFound = True
            End If
        Next CheckCell
        If Not CellFound Then
            CompareCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next CompareCell
End Sub
```

One thing to note is that this function assumes that you have a single column range. otherwise it will check all the cells in your ranges and probably highlight more than you intended.

**EDIT**
As far as Highlighting the Row
try adding this to your find loop

```
Dim CompareSheet as Worksheet 'Add at top of function

'Add to the For Each Loop
Set CompareSheet = temp.Worksheet
CompareSheet.Range("A" & temp.Row, "P" & temp.Row).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```

Comment: Based on the information Vivian provided so far, it could be one possible solution (just replacing column A by column C, which @Nathan wasn't able to know because he couldn't see the images).

Comment: @Nathan Fisher I have another problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784915/how-to-import-excel-related-bom-list-content-into-a-excel-sheet-in-excel-vba can you take a look and give me some suggestions on how to solve it?