# How to import Excel related BOM-list content into a excel sheet in Excel-VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, export-to-excel

How to implement a spreadsheet to do something more dynamic and recyclable for more user to use? By allowing the user to browse and import 2 excel related BOM-list files from the computer local drive into sheet 2/3 before i run the above code to find the differences?

Eg: Something like having two CommandButton's which can import all the excel BOM-list data information into sheet 2/3 without making any changes to the original? Before running any comparison test and a reset button for removeing all the content in sheet 2/3?

Sorry for my poor command of English and explanation if its not clear to you. Thanks for your time/help in advance. :)

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand what you were looking for ? What is your question ? What does not work in your code ? Btw, instead of `find`, you can use `countif` as described [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/VBALoops.htm)

Comment: @JMax Sorry for my poor explanation of what i want Because rather quite new to vba programming. I'm kinna confused on how to explain it either... Maybe its something like that in this link http://www.accessmvp.com/kdsnell/EXCEL_Import.htm#ImpBrowseFile I'm not quite sure either

Comment: @JMax It's like i'm having two excel document list. I wanted a set of vba codes on a excel file (current) which are capable of browsing and then select to import excel contents into this excel file (current)? Sorry for my poor explanation and English..

Comment: From what I can gather, what you are trying to do is import data from two Excel spreadsheets, and then compare the data on each list to find the missing elements in each list and then highlight the data row if it is missing

Comment: @Nathan Fisher i'm trying to to do what you have mention but i do not really know how i should implement the browse and import two excel spreadsheets?

Comment: @Nathan Fisher I have updated my codes above to only manage browse for the appropriate files, but i don't really know what i should do next like copying the content of that selected file and paste onto sheet 2/3?

Comment: @Nathan Fisher Any ideas how i can copy all the contents from that spreadsheet after i selected a file for my codes above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i still don't understand what you are looking for.

As far as i can read in your code, you are missing the **workbook manipulation** part.

You need to **open the workbook** you want to copy from with the `open` method as described [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming/374909-open-a-closed-workbook-with-vba.html).

Then, you can manipulate the workbook and its content as you have done in your code and as described [**in this tutorial**](http://www.anthony-vba.kefra.com/vba/vbabasic2.htm#Workbook_and_Worksheet_Object) .

Comment: After reading the article you gave me i'm still rather puzzled on what i should code next after opening the desired file? Must i really open and close the file in order to copy and paste the content into my current spreadsheet? If so how should i do it with my current context?

Comment: The code here kept giving me problem when the user did not choose a file any ideas how to solve this problem? Workbooks.Open Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks, *.xls; *.csv; *.xlsx", Title:="Importing Excel Spreadsheet 2")

Comment: @Vivian: opening the file to copy the data is the easiest way to cope with this (and to debug). To check if a user clicked `Cancel`, you can check the returned value as a boolean as described [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/td0009.html)

Comment: But i don't quite understand how to copy the selected excel file after it is opened as seen in my code above? Sorry rather new in programming..

Comment: In the link i gave you above, you can find a [chapter](http://www.anthony-vba.kefra.com/vba/vbabasic2.htm#Range_Object_and_Cells_Property) describing this part. Especially, you can do something like: `Wbk2.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = Wbk1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value`

Comment: @Vivian: if you are not familiar to Excel and programming, i advise you to start with some simple tutorials like [this one](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-VBA-Tutorial.html) or which ever you would find on the internet and create samples of codes. That will help you deeper than building from scratch big pieces of code like the one you are trying to do.

Comment: I've posted a question similar to what i'm doing here can you take a look and give me advice on could have gone with my code here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825157/whats-wrong-with-my-above-excel-vba-code