# What's wrong with my above Excel-VBA code?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

Brief description of what i want my VBA to achieve: I'm trying to import data from two Excel spreadsheets, and then compare the data on each list to find the missing elements in each list and then highlight the data row if it is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is a certain kind of order required to run Differences. Import_buttonx has to be called before  Differences can be called. So you get an out of index because stringOfSheet(1,2) probably ha no value. It's probably nil. You can check while debugging through your code.